# How to visualize any List<T> in a grid view in Visual Studio in the debugger?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, debuggervisualizer

There are dataset visualizers in Visual Studio. They are handy to view the data in a gridview like presentation in the debugger. Is there any way to do the same to view data in a list? Mole 2013, a discontinued commercial product, does this but it won't exist for Visual Studio 2015 and later.

Answer (score 1):

It is a pity that Molosoft didn't "open source" the last version of Mole, but the source code of V4.2 for VS2008 is still downloadable at [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22576/Mole-For-Visual-Studio-With-Editing-Visualize-All). It shouldn't be too hard to convert it to work with VS2015, if you are able and willing to invest some work you will get Mole for VS2015 and newer versions.

**Edit:** Sometimes you just have to make a wish and wait a while:
[Mole2015 (Open Source)](https://github.com/Oceanware/Mole2015)

Comment: Aaaaadn, that's gone now too.